# Powershell GetType from members of collection of variables

Tags: powershell, gettype

I have a collection of 4 variables as `(Get-Variable | Where Name -Match "^astr.*")`, array and text string variables mixed.
I'd like to see the type information of each of them for comparison reasons. If I type
   `$astr2.GetType()` I get for BaseType 'System.Array'.
For
   `$astr3.GetType()` I get 'System.Object', so I see the difference in their type.
However, so see all in one go via

```
Get-Variable | Where Name -Match "^astr.*" | Select {$_.GetType().BaseType}
```

I get 'System.Object' four times, but no different values.

Also

```
Get-Variable | Where Name -Match "^astr.*" | %{$_.GetType()}, or 
Get-Variable | Where Name -Match "^astr.*" | %{$_.GetType().BaseType}
```

do not give the expected. Why is the iteration not working?

Comment: PowerShell variables do not have a type as such; only their values do. If you explicitly declare a variable as having a type (e.g. `[int] $x = 0`), that just results in a variable with an `ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute` applied so later assignments respect the "type". (Retrieving that "type" is possible but not exactly easy, and it's not documented either.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert There's also the matter that the pipeline will unroll everything for you to be nice so in some situations you need to use the unary array `,` operator to prevent such unrolling and view collection members.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
Get-Variable | Where Name -Match "^astr.*" | Select {$_.Value.GetType()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dank u wel, Gert-Jan and Jeroen! Adding ".Value" works as expected, and is totally backed by Jeroen's comment's first 13 words... Great help!